# AS3 Sticksports Flurry Analytics

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flurry

Im working with the Stick Sports Flurry Native extension for an app made is AS3.

I have the main bits working and events registering but got stuck when it came to setting user age and user gender.

Just Wondering if anyone was familiar with how to do this

Thanks in advance

Jake

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code all you need to do is call the right function.  They're static, so use the class name as well.

```
    /**
     * Set user's id in your system.
     */
    Flurry.setUserId(id)  // String

    /**
     * Set user's age in years
     */
    Flurry.setUserAge(age) // int

    /**
     * Set user's gender ("m" or "f")
     */
    Flurry.setUserGender( gender ) // String
```

Comment: Sorry, thanks for your reply! Only just had a chance to get back to this. Trying it out now and will then need to wait for Flurry to update! Will let you know. thanks